# AJAX post PDF document and JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

I'm trying to POST a PDF document together with some stringified JSON data using an AJAX method (jQuery) to an ASP.NET WEB API (2). Here are my methods that do not work:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
//because the user must be authorized (getting the Token using a POST works just fine)
var header = { Authorization: "bearer " + user.access_token };
    $.ajax({
                url: url,
                headers: header,
                data: { json: stringData, pdf : pdfData},
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                method: 'POST'
            }).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log("succes");
                });
    
            }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("error");
            });
```

ASP.NET WEB API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("submit")]
    public string SubmitTemplate(SubmitTemplate template)
    {
        return "a thing happened";
            
    }
```

SubmitTemplate Model:

```
public class SubmitTemplate
    {
        public string json { get; set; }
        public string pdf { get; set; }
    }
```

Using postman this method works (see screenshot) be using the AJAX method above it does not.
It is for a mobile application (cross domain) if this info is helpful.

All help is appreciated a lot!
Thanks in advance.

(this is a image how postman is configured: [screenshot hosted on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiyqy.jpg))

EDIT: the `pdfData` is a pdf file made with jsPDF (`doc.output`), so I think it is the string as if you opened a PDF document using notepad(++).

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? What type of data is in `pdfData`? If it's a file, I'd assume binary data which could be the cause of your issue, as it can't be serialised

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No there are no errors in the console but using the network tab I can see that none of the data is send. I also edited my question. So it could very well be binary data, how would I send this using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was able to send all data to the server as strings, this is how the jQuery/JavaScript request now looks:

```
var obj = { json: stringData, pdf: pdfData };

$.ajax({
        url: url,
        headers: header,
        data: obj,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: "json"
    }).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("succes");
    }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

The server side stays the same.

Next step is to convert the string back to a PDF file (let's hope I don't spend 2 days on this :) ).

Comment: Why bother to convert the pdffile to a string at all? Send it as binary data to a `HttpPostedFileBase` using `FormData` in your JS code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I had problems with form data for whatever reason, no the pdf is convertedd te Base64 and send this way. This works even though the size of the base64 string is increased :/. I (and the team) also have a time limit and now that it works we can finally move on, even if it is not the best solution.

Comment: If we have time left on the project we will try it with FormData. Thanks for the help